# Jquery Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I use fancybox to zoom in images, how do I count the image views?

Comment: for what context ? not sure where you going with this ... maybe you need google analitics or maybe your counting them for some other purpose

Comment: I am going to presume you have many images on a page, and these images are arranged in a gallery as defined on http://fancybox.net/.

Your going to need to intercept the click on an image and the next/previous buttons for fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful for you

http://fancybox.net/api

Thanks,

Kanji